# Querying through associations with Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have a question about doing a query through a few associations using Ruby on Rails.

This question involves querying across three models. (Event, Fight, Fighters). The important parts of the models are as follows:

- An event has multiple fights.
- Each fight has two fighters: fighter1 and fighter2.

What I need to write is a function to retrieve a list of all fights that have a given fighter. However, this needs to be done through the Event model due to some weird localization thing we have running.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please provide your Event, Fight, and Fighters classes

Comment: What do you mean by "weird localization thing"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
class Event
  has_many :fights
end

class Fight
  has_many :fighters
end
```

Then you can do:

```
events = Event.joins(:fights => :fighters).where("fighters.name = 'sally'")
fights = events.inject([]){|a,e| a = a + e.fights; a }
```